db.create.setNodeVectorProperty not registered for this database instance
Failed to create vector index in the local Neo4j database (server version 5.3.0).
I noticed that the db.create.setNodeVectorProperty procedure is not installed on my local machine. I ran the "SHOW PROCEDURE" Cypher query to check its deployment status. Any assistance in finding and deploying the procedure would be greatly appreciated.

As documented, db.create.setNodeVectorProperty  was introduced in neo4j 5.13. In earlier versions of neo4j, you would use db.create.setVectorProperty.

Appreciated for your response - however I couldn't find db.create setVectorProperty procedure as well.

I think - have upgraded neo4j desktop version to the latest and still couldn't find the procedure installed in my local machine

Upgrading the software - it worked
